# AngularJS - How to extract or manipulate and display partial information of a bound value

Tags: json, angularjs

I would like to know how I can specifically select City and State from addresses in JSON file.

I'm looping through a JSON file using `ng-repeat` and I want to show part of the full address `{{user.currentAddress}}`.

`2728 Hill Croft Farm Road Sacramento CA 95814`

***Update***
Here's some of the retrieved objects.

```
analyst: "analyst1"
identityId: 1
parcelData: Object
   childrenNames: Array[3]
   currentAddress: "2728 Hill Croft Farm Road Sacramento CA 95814"
   employment: Array[1]
   name: "Melvin D Burg"
```

Comment: can you provide your json data structure?

Comment: without us seeing the structure of your JSON file, we really can't point in any direction to help you ... just copy-paste a part of it, so we can see the hierarchical structure and at least one full User element... replace the data with fake-data to ensure privacy

Comment: Here's the data structure.

Comment: look at npm module `humanparser`

Comment: I don't think he'd deserve a -1 just for not properly describing his problem. The problem as it is clear by now is a good question itself and deserves an answer... although you could find a thorough writeup about it in the angularjs documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the information you've given I think that

```
user.currentAddress = "2728 Hill Croft Farm Road Sacramento CA 95814";
```

In that case you may want to create a filter to split that information and show the part you want to display,

e. g. split that line and post only the state, city and zip:

```
yourApp.filter('showMyPreferredAddressPart', function () {
    return function (input) {
        var parts = input.split(' ');
        var zip = parts.pop();
        var state = parts.pop();
        var city = parts.pop();
        var road = parts.join(' ');
        return "<span class='zip'>"+zip+"</span><span class='city'>"+city"</span><span class='state'>"+state+"</span>;
    };
});
```

with that filter in your app you can later call it in your html like this:

```
<div class='address' ng-bind-html="user.currentAddress|showMyPreferredAddressPart"></div>
```

That filter example will of course only work if the last 3 parts of the 'currentAddress' always are 'city<blank>state<blank>zip' and if the city consists of one word only

if the format is different you might need a different approach

maybe you can get the creator of the JSON file to add ',' like

```
currentAddress = "90 Church St,New York,NY,10007";
```

to indicate the essential parts of the address... that would make it a lot easier for you to parse it and display the right parts

Comment: I'll definitely request for commas. Thanks for the tip and the example. It's very helpful. Once I add commas, I should split the parts using `var parts = input.split(',');' and keep the rest the same. I appreciate your detailed explanation. I know it wasn't easy with the incomplete data structure.

Comment: the problem was that it wasn't clear that you actually only wanted to split the full address string into its parts. from the first version of your question we were thinking that currentAddress would be an object with properties itself. but its ok. (btw: you'd have to replace `road = parts.join(' ')` by `road = parts.pop();`)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `{{user.parcelData.currentAddress}}` ?